# Which Application Server is used by Quarkus Internally?

Tags: jboss, quarkus

Like Spring Boot uses Apache Tomcat, Undertow and Jetty and i have worked on an assignment of same. So just trying to map understanding.

What application server is used by Quarkus?

```
I have created an application in server and found Jboss libaries, Arjuna Libraries for transaction 
which is used by Jboss servers or wildfly servers. But i am not sure whether it is based on Jboss.
```

Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, Quarkus can be thought of as its own application server. However, it is comprised of many open source libraries that have been around for a while, such as:

- RESTEasy for JAX-RS
- Undertow for the Servlet/Websocket engine
- Netty for the network IO layer
- Hibernate for JPA

The full set of extensions can be found on the [Quarkus Starter](https://code.quarkus.io/) website.